# ASP.net/Ajax POST request 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have ajax request in a .net webpage which triggers a webmethod returning data from database. **Everything works when deployed in IIS on my personal PC, but when deployed on a server I am receiving 500 Internal Server Error.**

Ajax request:

```
    function getData() {
        var $tbl = $('#tbl');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.aspx/GetData',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d.length > 0) {
                    var newdata = data.d;
                    $tbl.empty();
                    $tbl.append('<tr><th>ID</th></tr>');
                    var rows = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < newdata.length; i++) {
                        rows.push('<tr><td>' + newdata[i].ID + '</td</tr>');
                    }
                    $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                }
            }
        });
```

Any ideas?

*The website is deployed on IIS 8

Best Regards,
Alexander

Comment: A 500 response means there was a *server-side* error.  Do you have any logging in your application to capture and record errors?  Check that.  You can also configure your Web.config to show error details on the page as it does in debug mode (the "CustomErrors" setting), so the details of the error would then be in the response.  But basically you need to find out *what the error is* before you can correct it.

Comment: Show your code behind method please. It seems your server side method is throwing an exception.